# Company won't complete at the beginning of org mode headline

Tags: org-mode, company-mode

For example, with the given text

```
* algorithm
* algo<cursor>
```

Fun company-complete it won't complete the word `aglorithm`.

If the cursor is not at the beginning of a headline, then completion works as usual.

Comment: But it's not at the beginning? It's after "algo"?

Comment: yes.  I have to type something to start the conversion, give some word prefix to company for completion.

Comment: You can try `M-x company-diag` at that position for some additional information.

Comment: thanks. it is because of this issue:https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/342.  capf conflicts with dabbrev.